# Why does `nanosleep` need the argument of `req` while kernel has the chance to restart the system call again internally(`-ERESTARTSYS`)?

Tags: c, linux, kernel, driver

As per the documentation(https://lwn.net/Articles/17744/), which says "nanosleep(), which is currently the only user of this mechanism, need only save the wakeup time in the restart block, along with pointers to the user arguments..".

If so, why nanosleep needs a argument `req` whose type is `struct timespec *`.

As per the linux program manual, "int nanosleep(const struct timespec *req, struct timespec *rem); If the call is interrupted by a signal handler, nanosleep() returns -1, sets errno to EINTR, and writes the remaining time into the structure pointed to by rem unless rem is NULL. "

I think that if the kernel could restart the system call('do_nanosleep') internally, there is no need to return the duration that how long you have left to sleep again to the user space. That's what I could not understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ERESTARTSYS` should never be seen from user code, you are correct.  It is a flag for the kernel to restart a call itself, or return EINTR to user code.  Please see [this discussion on the Linux Kernel Mailing List](http://lkml.iu.edu/hypermail/linux/kernel/0111.2/1352.html):

> > So which way is it *supposed* to be (so someone can patch things up |>
> >     to make it consistent): |> |> 1. User space should never see
> >     ERESTARTSYS from any system call
>
> Yes. The kernel either transforms it to EINTR, or restarts the syscall
>   when the signal handler returns.

Or [this article](https://lwn.net/Articles/17744/) on LWN.net

> What happens, though, if a signal is queued for the process while it
>   is waiting? In that case, the system call needs to abort its work and
>   allow the actual delivery of the signal. For this reason, kernel code
>   which sleeps tends to follow the sleep with a test like:
>
> ```
> if (signal_pending(current))  return -ERESTARTSYS;
> ```
>
> After the signal has been handled, the system call will be restarted
>   (from the beginning), and the user-space application need not deal
>   with "interrupted system call" errors. For cases where restarting is
>   not appropriate, a -EINTR return status will cause a (post-signal)
>   return to user space without restarting the system call.

I don't think any of this has to do with `nanosleep(2)` params other than that under the cover it uses this mechanism.  [The nanosleep docs](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/nanosleep.2.html) tell you what the params do, `req` is how long you want to sleep, and `rem` is how long you have left if you get woken up early.

Comment: As per the documation aforementioned above, which says "nanosleep(), which is currently the only user of this mechanism, need only save the wakeup time in the restart block, along with pointers to the user arguments..". **If so, why `nanosleep` needs a arguent  whose  type is `struct  timespec  *req`. **  As per the linux program mannual, "int  nanosleep(const  struct  timespec  *req,  struct timespec  *rem);    If the call is interrupted by a  signal  handler,  nanosleep() returns -1, sets errno to EINTR, and writes the remaining time into the structure pointed to by rem unless rem is NULL. "

Comment: Please see my edit, I don't think these things are related

Comment: Thank you for your attention to this matter.I think that if **the kernel could restart the system call('do_nanosleep') internally**, there is **no need to return** the duration that how long you have left to sleep again to the user space. **That's what i could not understand.**

Answer (score 2):

The title of the question doesn't entirely match the actual question. @dsolimano did answer the title.

However, it seems that you're asking why code that calls `nanosleep()` needs to handle a case like `EINTR` if `ERESTARTSYS` presumably solves the problem in the kernel.

Assuming that this is the question, the answer is, that this is not the problem.

Here are a couple of use cases for `EINTR`:

1. You want to wait for a certain amount of time, but be able to handle signals synchronously (i.e. not in a signal handler). For example, you are waiting for a DB to initialize, but if the user presses Ctrl+C you want to show the current DB status and continue waiting.
2. You want to wait for a signal, but with a timeout. So you sleep for the timeout, but if `nanosleep()` returned `EINTR` you know you got a signal.

Regarding your "auxiliary questions", I'll tl;dr @dsolimano's answers:

> What are the differences between `ERESTARTSYS` and `EINTR`?

`ERESTARTSYS` is a kernel implementation detail, `EINTR` is part of the kernel's API.

> Is `ERESTARTSYS` only used in kernel or driver?

Yes.

> why does `nanosleep()` need an argument of type is `struct timespec *req`?

`req` is the number of nanoseconds to sleep. You probably meant `rem`. The first use case I outlined above is an example why.

Comment: One more question. As your example, the argument `rem` could indicate how long you have left to sleep, but it does not consider the duration that used by the signal handler, so i think if you call nanosleep like this `"nanosleep(rem, NULL)"`  is not right.

Comment: You probably want to call `nanosleep(rem, new_rem)`.

Comment: No sleep function guarantees not to "oversleep", so it's ok not to count the time spent in the signal handler.